# Convexity of single valued correspondence

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Is $\Psi(x):X\rightrightarrows Y\subset X $ is a single valued correspondence for  every x$\in$X. I have an application where i need to apply Kakutani's fixed point theorem. Now since the correspondence is single valued can i say that it is convex valued?. It seems to me that the condition is trivially satisfied. Am i getting something wrong here?

Regards